# Facebook Messenger Application Integration

Tags: java

I just tried to follow the official guidance from Facebook of how to integrate my application to Facebook Messenger.

Somewhere there is a Java statement with empty argument. Just dots "...".
Or, do I have to put the dots as is ?

```
Bitmap image = ...
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(image)
        .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();
```

or this:

```
Uri videoFileUri = ...
ShareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
        .setLocalUrl(videoUrl)
        .build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(video)
        .build();
```

Comment: It's not a valid statement, it's just a way of saying, "put some code here".

Comment: Thank you Tunaki. I think so. But what.